# How to update a column in a table using joins(with another table) with duplicate values in the linking fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables: A and B. A has five columns namely Co_ID, MODE, Ship_date, SCAC, BU, Condition
B has the following columns: Co_ID, Mode, Condition

The sample data in A is as below:

```
Co_ID   MODE    Ship_date   SCAC    BU  Condition
XYZ DV  10/5/2018   CEDD    XYZ 
XYZ DV  10/6/2018   CEDD    XYZ 
XYZ DV  10/6/2018   NAFQ    XYZ 
XYZ DV  10/7/2018   ABCD    XYZ 
XYZ DV  10/7/2018   PQRS    XYZ 
XYZ TC  10/4/2018   BLKW    XYZ 
XYZ TC  10/7/2018   BLKW    XYZ 
XYZ TC  10/7/2018   ABCD    XYZ 
XYZ TC  10/8/2019   PQRS    XYZ
```

The sample data in B is as below:

```
Co_ID   Mode    Condition
XYZ DV  A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('DV') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ DV  A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('DV') and A.Scac Not in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ TC  A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('TC') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ TC  A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and TransactionData_TL.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('TC') and A.Scac not in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')
```

Objective: Update the condition column in table A using the condition column in table B linking the Co_ID and mode columns.

Problem that I am facing: The condition column in table A is getting updated wrongly ,which means, for instance, all the rows(row 1 to 5) with Co_ID='XYZ' and mode='DV' in table A is getting wrongly updated to the first value of the condition column with Co_ID='XYZ' and mode='DV'(row 1) and not with their respective condition values of table B. I am not able to understand where the exact problem lies.

I have used a cursor based query to update the condition column in table A to condition column in table B linking the Co_ID and mode columns and providing the condition column in the where clause as below:

```
Declare @sql_program nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max)
Set @sql_program=''
Set @sql=''

Declare CONDITION_CURSOR Cursor for

Select 'Update A
Set A.Condition = B.Condition
From A inner join B
on A.Co_ID = B.Co_ID and A.mode = B.mode  ' + ' and ' + 
CASE WHEN (LTRIM(RTRIM(B.Condition)) is null) THEN '' ELSE (LTRIM(RTRIM(B.Condition))) END
From B


Open CONDITION_CURSOR

Fetch next from CONDITION_CURSOR into @sql_program
While(@@FETCH_STATUS!=-1)
    Begin
        If(@sql_program is not null)
            Begin
                If(@sql is null or @sql = '')
                    Begin
                        Set @sql = @sql_program
                    End
                Else
                    Begin
                        Set @sql = @sql + ' ; '+ @sql_program
                    End
            end

Fetch next from CONDITION_CURSOR into @sql_program
End
Close CONDITION_CURSOR
Deallocate CONDITION_CURSOR
Select @sql as Condition_query
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

The expected output should be as below:

```
Co_ID   MODE    Ship_date   SCAC    BU  Condition
XYZ DV  10/5/2018   CEDD    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('DV') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW')and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ DV  10/6/2018   CEDD    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('DV') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ DV  10/6/2018   NAFQ    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('DV') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ DV  10/7/2018   ABCD    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('DV') and A.Scac Not in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ DV  10/7/2018   PQRS    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('DV') and A.Scac Not in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW')  and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ TC  10/4/2018   BLKW    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('TC') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ TC  10/7/2018   BLKW    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('TC') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ TC  10/7/2018   ABCD    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('TC') and A.Scac not in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW')  and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ TC  10/8/2019   PQRS    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('TC') and A.Scac not in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW')  and A.BU in('XYZ')
```

The actual output that I am getting currently is as below:

```
Co_ID   MODE    Ship_date   SCAC    BU  Condition
XYZ DV  10/5/2018   CEDD    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('DV') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ DV  10/6/2018   CEDD    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('DV') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ DV  10/6/2018   NAFQ    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('DV') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ DV  10/7/2018   ABCD    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('DV') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ DV  10/7/2018   PQRS    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('DV') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ TC  10/4/2018   BLKW    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('TC') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ TC  10/7/2018   BLKW    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('TC') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ TC  10/7/2018   ABCD    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('TC') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')

XYZ TC  10/8/2019   PQRS    XYZ A.Co_id = 'XYZ' and A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('TC') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')
```

Comment: I would try to `PRINT @sql` and see what it looks like before executing it. Even better, see first what the output of that select statement in the cursors is... does it look like what you need in the first place?

Comment: @sql basically holds the output of the select statement of cursor. And the output of select statement of cursor looks like this(written 1 set of statements below for reference):
```sql  
-- select statement output
Update A
Set A.Condition = B.Condition
From A inner join B
on A.Co_ID = B.Co_ID and A.mode = B.mode 
where A.Ship_date>='2018-10-01' and A.Ship_date<='2018-12-31' and A.mode in('DV') and A.Scac in('CEDD','NAFQ','BLKW') and A.BU in('XYZ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Update a Set 
a.condition = b.condition FROM tableA a inner join tableB b on
a.Co_Id = b. Co_Id

Comment: although the query doesn't return any errors, the output would be wrong and doesn't meet my question requirement.